# Sub references within a table / report generating to show sub references in access

Tags: ms-access, report

I'm using Access 2010 and I have inherited a table that contains training subjects.  Some of those subjects are primary subjects and some are sub areas of main subjects (all in the same table).  The main table is indexed by number:

```
ID  |   Type    |   Department  |   Subject                         |   Sub 1   |   Sub 2   |   Sub 3
----+-----------+---------------+-----------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------
1   |   Main    |   Candy       |   Chocolate covered bananas       |   2       |   3       |   4
2   |   Sub     |   Candy       |   Melting Chocolate               |           |           |
3   |   Sub     |   Candy       |   Dipping machine                 |           |           |
4   |   Sub     |   Candy       |   Freezer Operation               |           |           |
5   |   Main    |   Candy       |   Chocolate covered Strawberries  |   2       |   3       |
```

I am attempting to make a report that would show the main subject and then everything that is a sub requirement of the main subject.  So the report would look like this:

***Candy Department***

**Chocolate Covered Bananas**
- Melting Chocolate
- Dipping Machine
- Freezer Operation
**Chocolate Covered Strawberries**
- Melting Chocolate
- Dipping Machine

etc...

I can't figure out how to get the relationships or lookup commands correct to get the references right.  I am starting to suspect that I have to split the table in to two - one for main subjects and one for sub-requirements.  This isn't a great option, though, because it's a bit of a big table and is linked to other reports and queries.  Some of these subjects contain up to 10 sub-areas (there are more fields in the table than I indicated here, but a lot of it isn't really necessary for the solution)

Comment: Splitting the table seems like a good idea, as much as I hate to say (because it sounds like a lot of work)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Is there any meaning attached to the numbers  in the Sub 1 thru 3 field names?  Would Sub 1 = 2 and Sub 2 = 3 mean something different than Sub 1 = 3 and Sub 2 = 2?

Comment: @HansUp - Thanks!  The numbers in the sub fields are simply pointers that indicate the ID of the sub level training that they are included in the main.  So Sub 1 = 3 means that the Dipping Machine training is a subcomponent of the main training.

Comment: Thanks again to all - including the good folks who edited my orignial post to make it look like it was supposed to. The solution from Josh, below, nailed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by writing a "Union" query.

Select the "SQL" view mode in Access to work with this type of query.

The Goal here is to "unpivot" the data, so that each sub type has a reference back to the main type.

```
SELECT  Table1.ID AS MainID
      , Table1.Department AS MainDepartment
      , Table1.Subject AS MainSubject
      , Table1_1.ID AS SubID
      , Table1_1.Department AS SubDepartment
      , Table1_1.Subject AS SubSubject
FROM    Table1
        INNER JOIN Table1 AS Table1_1 ON Table1.[Sub 1] = Table1_1.ID
UNION
SELECT  Table1.ID AS MainID
      , Table1.Department AS MainDepartment
      , Table1.Subject AS MainSubject
      , Table1_1.ID AS SubID
      , Table1_1.Department AS SubDepartment
      , Table1_1.Subject AS SubSubject
FROM    Table1
        INNER JOIN Table1 AS Table1_1 ON Table1.[Sub 2] = Table1_1.ID
UNION
SELECT  Table1.ID AS MainID
      , Table1.Department AS MainDepartment
      , Table1.Subject AS MainSubject
      , Table1_1.ID AS SubID
      , Table1_1.Department AS SubDepartment
      , Table1_1.Subject AS SubSubject
FROM    Table1
        INNER JOIN Table1 AS Table1_1 ON Table1.[Sub 3] = Table1_1.ID;
```

Your output should have 1 row for each sub type.
[image: Union query results]

Comment: Thanks - this looks like it will work and I'm eager to try it.  I have 10 sub subjects, and I'm a newbie at this and haven't gotten into SQL at all, so it may take me a day or so, but I will let you know what I find.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you! - This is exactly what I needed.  I'll have to tweak the reporting a bit to get it to look like I want to, and I had to add a lot of subfields that I didn't include in the original sample, but you've put me on the right track.  Sorry I didn't get back to you earlier, I didn't even have a chance to open access yesterday.  It's not my main job, but I keep getting thrown projects and am teaching myself as I go.  Very helpful - I can't thank you enough.

Comment: The only thing I had to add was to add a section for main training areas that did not have subdepartments.  (With the query above, those just didn't show because there wasn't a sub area) so I added everything the same with the extra line of:     INNER JOIN Table1 AS Table1_1 ON Table1.[ID] = Table1_1.ID